# Loading a document in XSLT using BASIC authentication in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, xml, xslt

For development purposes we have a site setup with BASIC authentication in IIS7. One aspect of the site is that it does a lot transformations using XSLT. However this is causing authentication problems when loading documents in XSLT like this:

```
<xsl:with-param 
     name="value" 
     select="document('/mod_cms/xml/fixed/phaedrus_object_menu_display.xml')
                /menuDisplay/option[value=$pagingValue]/name"/>
```

I get the error:

> `The remote server returned an error:
>   (401) Unauthorized.`

Looking on the web for solutions, I have come across suggestions to use Credentials, eg:

```
Dim sw As New StringWriter()
Dim xslArg As New XsltArgumentList()
Dim xslt As New XslCompiledTransform()
Dim settings As New XsltSettings
settings.EnableDocumentFunction = True
Dim resolver As New XmlUrlResolver
Dim xml As New XmlDocument
xml.LoadXml(sXml)

Dim myCache As New System.Net.CredentialCache()
myCache.Add(New Uri("http://URL.net/"), "Basic", New System.Net.NetworkCredential("???", "???"))
myCache.Add(New Uri("http://URL.net/mod_cms/xml/fixed/"), "Basic", New System.Net.NetworkCredential("???", "???"))
resolver.Credentials = myCache '

xslt.Load(sXsl, settings, resolver)
xslt.Transform(xml, xslArg, sw)
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

Has someone else had this problem.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Which XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: I am using the ASP.Net inbuilt one (System.Xml and System.Xml.Xsl)

Comment: If the application/service calling the transformation has enough privilege to access the resource, you could get the resource first and pass it as parameter instead of letting the default value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using an **[XmlUrlResolver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669135.aspx)** object.

Comment: I believe I am doing. I have edited my question to provide more of the code.